# C# tablelayoutpanel panel control

Tags: c#, controls, panel, tablelayoutpanel

I have a tablelayoutpanel divided in 4 columns and 4 rows. by using `Panel box = new Panel();` I filled in all 4x4 tablelayout panel with panels. now I have to delete in example a Panel which is in 2 collumn and 3 row. how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, but try this one;

```
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(col, row));
```

This is assuming you're just trying to remove the panels (As they would be child controls to the tableLayoutPanel).

Otherwise you could remove directly by passing the actual panel you want to remove through the method;

```
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(panelYouWantToRemove);
```